# How to integrate the Android Support Repository in an IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.1 project using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm working in an IBM MobileFirst 7.1 project using Eclipse Mars but when I'm trying to deploy my app in a device, the app stops and the error is related to android/support/v4/view/GestureDetectorCompat class. I'm using the support library 19 because this is a jar file, however if I want to use the 25 or 26 alpha I can't find the way to convert the .aar file to .jar and keep working with Eclipse IDE.

Is any way to work with a support library updated with this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick fix, you can extract the .aar file which will contain the classes.jar which you can use in Eclipse.

Comment: I'll mark this answer as a solution, but is a partial solution because the support library only has the classes that I need until the 24.1.1 version. From the 24.2.0 the .class files are not there.